# Как реализовать настраиваемый цвет в месте пересечения объектов на CSS (или JS)?

Tags: javascript, css, веб-программирование

Возможно ли организовать на CSS либо через JS пересечение текста и картинки, как на макетах ниже? Не абы с какими цветами, интересует возможность выбрать конкретный цвет для пересечения. Если возможно, то дайте пример, пожалуйста.

[image: Макет 1]

[image: Макет 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение через только CSS:

```css
div {
  --r: 90px;
  --d: calc(var(--r) * 2);
  position: relative;
  width: var(--d); height: var(--d);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #888 center/cover no-repeat;
}

div p {
  --x: 120px;
  --y: 98px;
  --color: #0ef; 
  width: 0; height: 0;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  font: 2rem sans-serif;
}

div p::before,
div p::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--y); left: var(--x);
  white-space: pre;
}

div p::after {
  color: var(--color);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px var(--color);
  clip-path: circle(
    var(--r) at
    calc(var(--r) - var(--x))
    calc(var(--r) - var(--y))
  );
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/300');">
  <p data-text="Lorem ipsum&#xa;dolor sit amet"></p>  <!-- с переносами текста - такая вот беда, увы... -->
</div>
```

Цвет задается значением css-переменной `--color`.
Маска текста считается полуавтоматически, настройка размеров и координат выполняется тоже через css-переменные: `--r` - радиус круга (определяет размер родительского элемента), `--x` и `--y` - координаты текста относительно родительского элемента.
Эти координаты можно и автоматически считать, из радиуса/диаметра круга (что сделает компонент респонсивным)... а при желании, можно еще и размер шрифта учесть в подсчете - чтобы совсем адаптивно было. Но тут я сделал попроще, чтобы с переменными можно было поиграть через devtools браузера, подвигать текст в разные стороны.

*// Свойство `text-shadow` у `::after` снижает видимость черных краев у букв с наложением (толщиной примерно в полпикселя). Эти края от антиалиасинга, и не во всех браузерах будут торчать, но ослабить их просто, так почему бы и нет... Кстати, этот побочный эффект (черные края) хоть и выглядит не шибко эстетично, может быть полезен с практической стороны: его можно использовать для улучшения читаемости светлого текста на светлом фоне.*

Comment: Большое спасибо, это то, что нужно. Изящное решение!) Отдельное спасибо за разъяснения)

Comment: @devildev, пожалуйста! Обрати внимание, что ключевой трюк тут с "клонированием" текста (без скрипта такое возможно только из data-атрибута) и маской через свойство `clip-path` - для нормальной работы второго в вебкит браузерах, перед ним надо указать и префиксный вариант `-webkit-clip-path` (или использовать autoprefixer). С остальным, проблем не должно возникнуть (дохлый IE конечно в пролете, как обычно, в нем это все заработает только с полифиллами).

Answer (score 5):

Знаю решение через JS. Можно создать клон текста, разместить его внутри необходимых фигур, поставить в то же место где находится оригинальный текст и обрезать родительским блоком.

```js
const text = document.querySelector('.text');
const textOffset = offset(text);

[...document.querySelectorAll('.shape')].forEach((shape, index) => {
  const clone = text.cloneNode(true);
  clone.classList.add(`text-color-${index}`);
  const shapeOffset = offset(shape);
  clone.style.top = `${-1 * (shapeOffset.top - textOffset.top)}px`;
  clone.style.left = `${-1 * (shapeOffset.left - textOffset.left)}px`;
  shape.append(clone);
});

function offset(element) {
  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  const scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
  const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  return {
    top: rect.top + scrollTop,
    left: rect.left + scrollLeft,
  };
}
```

```css
.text.text-color-0 {
  color: red;
}

.text.text-color-1 {
  color: blue;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: green;
  z-index: -10;
}

.shape {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.shape .text {
  z-index: 10;
}

.circle {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  top: -160px;
  left: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #00cfff;
}

.rect {
  height: 50px;
  width: 120px;
  top: 10px;
  left: -50px;
  background: #ffcfff;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape circle"></div>
<div class="shape rect"></div>
<span class="text">QWERTY</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.text {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url("https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/circle-xxl.png");
  background-size: 100px, 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Ваш какой либо текст</div>
<img src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-vxsr4nt/images/stencil/960w/products/48647/23298/Dark_Blue_Inventory_Circle_Labels__81166.1380722758.jpg?c=2" class="image" />
```

Здесь я взял две картинки с кругом. Одну как `background-image` , другую за текстом придав самому тексту `position: absolute;`. Размеры картинок сделал одинаковыми и убрал повторения бэкграунд изображения `background-repeat: no-repeat;`. Этот способ не такой изящный, но довольно легкий.