# Как сделать такое изменения текста в области кртинки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Дизайнер нарисовал вот такой переход по цвету в тексте мало того так есть и места где картинка сдвигается и переход должен сохраняться, на фоне цвет не белый.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот пусть дизайнер и объяснит как это реализовать. Нормальные веб дизайнеры должны хоть немного ориентироваться в верстке, что бы не творить всякую дичь.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как реализовать настраиваемый цвет в месте пересечения объектов на CSS (или JS)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1303648/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-css-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-js)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему через дополнительный текст который спозиционировал absolute и через свойство clip-path сделал ограничение по тексту и через js пересчитывать создания polygon для clip-path.